# HTTPServletRequest does not include the file data in the request parameter flashUploadFiles

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

The browser request does contain the payload. eg:

```
Request Payload:
------------Ij5ei4ae0cH2GI3ei4KM7Ef1cH2Ef1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

uploadAsset1.csv
------------Ij5ei4ae0cH2GI3ei4KM7Ef1cH2Ef1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="collection"

26
------------Ij5ei4ae0cH2GI3ei4KM7Ef1cH2Ef1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="flashUploadFiles"; filename="uploadAsset1.csv"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------------Ij5ei4ae0cH2GI3ei4KM7Ef1cH2Ef1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

Submit Query
------------Ij5ei4ae0cH2GI3ei4KM7Ef1cH2Ef1--
```

The "flashUploadFiles" parameter contains the payload, but I am unable to parse the contents sometimes. I am using tapestry framework and apache.commons.io for getting the items. eg:

```
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List<FileItem> items = null;
            try {           
                items = upload.parseRequest(req);
            } catch (FileUploadException e) {               
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//items.size is zero
}
```

But, the items list is always empty.

The funny part is that if I restart my Jetty server, the same approach works and I am able to get the items listing. Am I missing something in Tapestry configuration?
Is there some other way to get the contents of the file uploaded using the parameter "flashUploadFiles" (which only contains the filename)?
I cant use request.getPart() method as we have not yet migrated to Servlet 3.0

Comment: Did you check if the file is empty?

Comment: yes! the file is there, infact i even checked the contentlength of the request, and the same is varying with the size of the file that i upload.